# How to call methods chosen by users on defined object?

Tags: ruby

Derive a class from String which defines a few methods on Strings, eg exclude? (opp of include). Also few methods which accepts arguments(required + optional).

From the command line, 
* Create an object by asking user an input string of the new class 
* Display all the method to user you defined (not defined by string or superclass) 
* Prompt user for a method name to call on the object
* Ask any required/optional argument required for this method
* Once the user enters the method name and arguments, execute it and display the results on the command line.

Storing the reference of dynamic class in an instance variable and calling methods over that instance variable inside call method. But at runtime none of those is getting called even if method exits inside class. Any suggestions ?

```
class String
   def initialize(class_name)
     @klass = Class.new
     Object.const_set(class_name, @klass)
   end

   def palindrome?
     self == self.reverse
   end

   def append(apnd)
     self.to_s + "\n" + apnd
   end

   def new_method(method_name, code_str)
     @klass.instance_eval do
         define_method(method_name) { instance_eval(code_str)}
     end
   end

   def call(method_name)
     if @klass.respond_to?(method_name) && %w[palindrome? append].include?(method_name)
       @klass.send(method_name)
     end
   end
end

puts "Please enter the class name:"
class_name = gets.chomp


puts "Please enter the method name you wish to define:"
method_name = gets.chomp

puts "Please provide any optional arguments for entered method:"
code_str = gets.chomp

obj = String.new(class_name)
puts obj.call(method_name)
```

```
#Expected result : Entered method should be evaluated on user provided argument.
"Please enter the method name you wish to define:" => palindrome?
"Please provide any optional arguments for entered method:" =>  GAG
output => true 
#As palindrome input argument was a palindrome hence method should evaluate #statement or block true for given object.
```

Comment: You are asked to derive a class from `String` (`class Substring < String`), but be careful, subclassing Ruby's core classes can be tricky.

Comment: "Any suggestions" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, make sure to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I guess below solution works, but still found few glitches while evaluating block .

```
class NewClass < String
   # Returns true if the string is its own reverse.
   def initialize(class_name)
     @klass = Class.new
     Object.const_set(class_name, @klass)
     display_methods
   end

   def palindrome?
     self == self.reverse
   end

   def append(apnd)
     self.to_s + "\n" + apnd
   end

   def new_method(method_name, code_str)
     @klass.instance_eval do
         define_method(method_name) { eval "#{code_str}"}
     end
   end

   def call(method_name)
     if @klass.respond_to?(method_name)
       @klass.public_send(method_name)
     end
   end
end

puts "Please enter the class name:"
class_name = gets.chomp

puts " Select your method from 'palindrome?' or 'append' "

puts "Please enter the method name you wish to define:"
method_name = gets.chomp

puts "Please provide any optional arguments for entered method:"
code_str = gets.chomp

obj = NewClass.new(class_name)
puts obj.method(method_name).call
```